# Execute function after $mddialog.cancel() finishes - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I've been looking at the documentation for $mdDialog.cancel() but haven't found how to call a function after if finishes.

I want to do something like this

```
$mdDialog.cancel().then(function() {
    // Do some stuff in here
});
```

Is this possible?

I thought of making a seperate function that returned a promise but not sure how to do that,

```
closeDialog().then(function(){
    // Do something
});

closeDialog = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, $mdDialog.cancel() returns a promise that is resolved when the dialog has been closed. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#cancel

Answer (score 1):

Your original approach was almost correct. You just need to return `$mdDialog.cancel()` from `closeDialog` function:

```
closeDialog().then(function() {
    // Do something
});

closeDialog = function() {
    return $mdDialog.cancel();
}
```